# Subsection numbering

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I used the following code and got the result below:

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}\roman{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesection.\alph{subsubsection}}


\section{title}
\subsection{title}
\subsubsection{title}

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: Result]

I want the subsection and subsection to look like this:

> 1 title
>
> 1.i title
>
> 1.i.a title

I would really appreciate if someone can helo me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do incremental definitions:

```latex
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\roman{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\alph{subsubsection}}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked!